# a simple formula linking the value of $e$ to the Golden Ratio $\phi$

Tags: constants

These last days, I was looking for an approximation formula to $\pi$. But, surprisingly, the formulas led to this other one:

$$
e = \left (\frac {\phi} {\phi - 1} \right)^{\frac {1} {2\text{Log}\phi}}\text{where }\phi\text { is the Golden Ratio} : \phi = \frac {1 + \sqrt {5}} {2}
$$

Personally, I've never heard about something similar. Does someone know something about this result?

EDIT1: I would like to apology. The answer is so obvious that I didn't see it, because I got it by more complicated (than necessary) equations solving. I didn't really check my result and asked the question before really thinking to it. I've flagged this question to be deleted. sorry.

Comment: Is only a bit more surprising that $e^{\log x}=x$. The equation $\phi^2=\phi+1$ does the rest.

Comment: thank you @martin, I feel really bad about this question. See my EDIT1 on the answer.

Comment: Don't feel bad. The question is simple but interesting. I've upvoted it.

Comment: thank you @Martin, but I feel bad anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(\phi/(\phi-1))=\phi^2,$ after raising both sides to the $\log \phi$ this relation becomes an identity.

Answer (score 3):

Here a simple one (smile):

$$\log{e}=\phi+1/\phi$$

Answer (score 0):

$$e = \left (\frac {\phi} {\phi - 1} \right)^{\frac {1} {2\text{Log}\phi}}\iff
\phi^2=(e^{\log\phi})^2=\frac{\phi}{\phi-1}=\cdots
$$